# Confused about the currently installed version of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Someone has installed sql server on my machine, however i'm not sure what is the version currently installed. I tried running : Sql server installation center --> Installed Sql server features discovery report and the result was as follows:

[image]

I tried looking in the "Programs and features" section and I found this: 
[image]

I also tried opening Sql server Services but its empty. Here's a screenshot: 
[image]

The currently running the services are : 
[image]
Currently I'm not sure what version is installed, I tried connecting to "." on Sql Management Studio but i got connection error and no instance was found.

Comment: Is the SQL Server Windows Service running? If it isn't, starting that may let you get into it via SSMS and allow you to query for the SQL version.

Comment: I tried opening "Services" and the only service i found that has the name "SQL" in it is "SQL Server VSS writer" and it's running. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't connect, probably the best thing to do is hunt it down on your file system.  Go to your installation, it's probably located somewhere like this:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQSERVER\MSSQL\Binn
```

and find the sqlserver.exe file.  Right-click and select Properties on the file.  The Details tab of the properties window will show a product version.  The product version isn't going to be a name you're super familiar with, but you can look up on the web what version numbers correspond to what product names.  Here's one place that has a nice chart.  [SqlServerBuilds at Blogspot](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/)

If you do get management studio to connect, you can get the version quite quickly, either from the connection properties in the Object Explorer, or with the ad hoc query

```
Select @ @Version
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can't find "MSSQL11.MSSQServer folder, i only got folders called "80, 90, 100,110,120"

Comment: If you don't have any instances in your program files, and your configuration manager is empty, and your installation discovery report came back with 'none' for every field, then you're in a pretty solid place to conclude that SQL server really isn't installed.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled 2008 and 2014 version and now the discovery report shows Sql Server 2012 installation correctly

Answer (score 0):

The existing answer is OK, but here is a simpler tip:

Search the entire drive C: for `sqlservr.exe`. Use the properties dialog in Explorer to determine the file version and Google it.

You can find out what's running with Process Explorer. It can show you the path and version.